# Invariant theory and congruence subgroups

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request, invariant-theory

Let $S$ be a polynomial ring and $G$ a group acting on it. When $G$ is a finite group, on modular or non-modular cases, there is a systematic method to find generators of the subalgebra $S^{G}$ or to compute the upper bound for the largest degree of generators. When $G$ is linearly reductive, we know that $S^{G}$ is finitely generated and we can study $S^G$ algebraically or geometrically (using GIT, representation theory, etc).

My question is when $G=\Gamma(N)$ is a congruence subgroup, is there any systematic method in the literature to study the generators of $S^{G}$? And to study in general the quotient of varieties by congruence subgroups?

Comment: Every action of an algebraic group $G$ on a finitely generated $k$-algebra $S$ has the property that for every finite-dimensional $k$-subspace $V$ of $S$, there exists a finite-dimensional $k$ subspace $W$ of $S$ that contains $V$ and that is mapped to itself by the action of $G$.  For any action of a group $G$ on $S$ that has this property, the ring of invariants $S^G$ equals $S^{\overline{G}}$, where $\overline{G}$ is the Zariski closure of the image of $G$ in the automorphism group of $S$.  If $\overline{G}$ is geometrically reductive, then you can use GIT to study $S^{\overline{G}}$.

Comment: I do not know what happens when $SL_n(\mathbb{Z})$ acts on $\mathbb{Z}^n=X^*(T)$ where $T$ is the algebraic $n$-torus. If we now take $S$ to be the coordinate ring of $T\times \cdots\times T$ a number of times, the action on $S$ does not have the property that a finite dimensinal $G$ stable subspace generates the algebra.